# Safely mixing methanol and chloroform

Tags: safety

Sorry for what is likely a naive question. I haven't worked with chemicals at all and have only had some brief lab safety instruction.

I need to create a mixture of chloroform and methanol 2:1 for a lipid extraction from bone.

I have read the safety data sheets for both chemicals but can't find any other information about how to safely create this mixture other than doing it in a fume hood. I need about 200 ml total.

If anyone has any information or can direct me to where to look that would be MUCH appreciated.

Thank you!!!

Comment: What kind of work environment are you in?  What kind of equipment do you have access to?

Comment: Mixing chloroform and methanol presents no hazards, **except for those presented by handling chloroform by itself and methanol by itself**.  That is, mixing these reagents does not create any dangerous reactions.  However, chloroform is a toxin and methanol is both a toxin and is highly flammable.

Comment: It will be in a lab at a university, although one that is not used frequently. I have access to everything I imagine I'll need safety wise (gloves, lab coat, safety glasses, etc). There is a fume hood, glassware, that kind of thing. Anything specific I will need?

Comment: I guess I just wanted to make sure there weren't any special precautions to be taken. So I can literally just pour the right amounts into a beaker or something like that? I wasn't sure if it had to be done in a special way.

Comment: @Heather, that's right.  Just mix.  Nothing will react.

Comment: Just be sure the hood draws air.

Comment: And dispose of residues into a chlorinated solvents labelled vessel

Comment: And mix well because their densities are very different

Comment: Don't over think.  At this level every simple manipulation would take weeks ;) I assume you don't that near flame or red hot surface nor you indulge in smelling atop.

Answer (score -2):

I am sorry to give my opinion here but I feel compelled to do so!

Security officers or the people writing the safety data sheet are motivated by only one thing: they don't want to be held liable! For them, everything is deadly and they don't even try to mitigate that (true) fact according to their audience.

As a result, all the risks are presented at the same level and nobody can really adjust his/her practices according to that.

I vividly remember one of my students at Oxford University. The rule there is(was?) that the student should copy the whole safety sheet on a form submitted to the Safety Officer before he/she can even get the chemical. My student had to do that for a ridiculous amount of cyanide and he was so stressed out that he ended up shaking and putting cyanide everywhere! I mean on the balance, around the balance, on the floor etc... I had to be besides him "It's OK, it's no big deal" while making signs to the others to not come around because there was cyanide everywhere.

So @Heather, I really advise you to ask your co-workers about the **true** risks in your field. You won't die because you had a whiff of chloroform or methanol, even though you should always work under a hood so you don't have a whiff of nasty materials. Also the safety sheets must be adapted to your own risks.